# GUI not displaying content till resized or minimised

Tags: java, swing, calculator

okay ... my question is rather straight forward so I doubt ill need to add any code but I will if need be.

Whenever I create a GUI frame and add a couple of panels to it and run my application, the contents are not displayed until I either re-size the window or minimize it on the toolbar then restore it. What could be the cause of that and how can I solve it?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
public final class Calculator extends JFrame  
{
    //initialise various variables for use within the program
    //BUTTONS
    private final JButton additionButton = new JButton("+"); 
    private final JButton subtractionButton = new JButton("-");
    private final JButton divisionButton = new JButton("/");
    private final JButton multiplicationButton = new JButton("*");    

    //PANELS
    private JPanel operatorPanel;
    private JPanel operandPanel;

    //LABELS
    private JLabel operationLabel;    

    //constructor to initialise the frame and add components into it
    public Calculator()
    {
        super("Clancy's Calculator");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));
        setSize(370, 200);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        //create a message label to display the operation that has just taken place
        operationLabel = new JLabel("YOU HAVE PERFORMED SOME OPERATION",SwingConstants.CENTER);

        add(getOperatorPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(getOperandPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(operationLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    //setter method for the operator panel
    public void setOperatorPanel()
    {
        operatorPanel = new JPanel();
        operatorPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        operatorPanel.add(additionButton);
        operatorPanel.add(subtractionButton);
        operatorPanel.add(multiplicationButton);
        operatorPanel.add(divisionButton);
    }
    //getter method for the operator panel
    public JPanel getOperatorPanel()
    {
        setOperatorPanel();
        return operatorPanel;
    }

    //setter method for operands panel
    public void setOperandPanel()
    {
        operandPanel = new JPanel();
        operandPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));

        //LABELS
        JLabel operandOneLabel = new JLabel("Enter the first Operand: ");
        JLabel operandTwoLabel = new JLabel("Enter the second Operand: ");
        JLabel answerLabel = new JLabel("ANSWER: ");

        //TEXT FIELDS
        JTextField operandOneText = new JTextField();   //retrieves one operand
        JTextField operandTwoText = new JTextField();   //retrieves another operand
        JTextField answerText = new JTextField();   //displays answer

        answerText.setEditable(false);  //ensure the answer field is not editable

        operandPanel.add(operandOneLabel);
        operandPanel.add(operandOneText);
        operandPanel.add(operandTwoLabel);
        operandPanel.add(operandTwoText);
        operandPanel.add(answerLabel);
        operandPanel.add(answerText);

    }
    //getter method for operand panel
    public JPanel getOperandPanel()
    {
        setOperandPanel();
        return operandPanel;
    }

    /** main method */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Calculator();
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be nice if you added some code...

Comment: if this is swing just call `repaint()` after you add the panels

Comment: Well without any code my guess would be your JFrame is not properly sized for the panels you are adding to it.

Comment: The cause is a bug in the code. My crystal ball says it's at line 453, but it doesn't say which file, unfortunately.

Comment: @JBNizet darn you really need to get the crystal ball 2.0 it can tell you all you wish to know.

Comment: Your crystal ball is on steroids JB coz im only at line 100, but i guess thats an implication that I shouldve added some code and ill do that shortly.

Comment: Do you call `pack()` on your frame before displaying it? Otherwise please post some code (@JBNizet +1 for the hilarious comment lol)

Comment: @c.s. has your likely problem and it's solution -- call `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` **after** adding all your components to the GUI (if this is Swing). Next time, please post code with your question as well as the name of the GUI library you're using. The more informative the question, usually the better the answer. We of course don't want to see all the code as that could drown us in unrelated code, and figuring out how much to show is as much an art as it is a science. Often the best thing to show is an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please check out the link.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ... thanks for the tips - im just getting used to stack ... unfortunately ive already posted the "cumbersome code". I guess the problem was with pack(). and thanks you all, I think this question can be peacefully marked as solved. JB ... I wouldve +1'ed your comment if I knew my way around StackOverflow but thanks alot. cheers for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you're programatically setting a new layout manager.  Whenever you add, remove or change a java gui, you need to call `invalidate()` or `revalidate()` to make java re-create the GUI.  See if calling `invalidate()` before `setVisible(true)` fixes the problem